# Audio keeps dissapearing mid sentence only during Voice chat

Tags: windows, audio, drivers

my friend keeps disappearing mid-sentence. He said that his Microphone and Audio just stops for about a second. It happens on Discord and Teamspeak. He said that he updated his Drivers. Every other Audio Source is working, even when it happens just the Voice Chat is affected.
I presume it's a Windows Driver problem.
He uses the Corsair Void elite Headset and is on Windows 10.

I suggested trying a quick Linux boot stick to check if it's a hardware or Windows problem and at worst a reset, but he would do it as the last option.

Comment: Have you considered that the issue might be at your end?

Comment: its not on our end we tested it with multiple people